# MongoDB's $setUnion does not work on array of arrays generated by $push

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to perform a complex aggregation query on some collection (MongoDB 3.4). In this aggregation I have a need to get rid of duplicates, and to do this I wish to use the `$setUnion` operator.

Please consider the following:

```
const a = ObjectId();
const b = ObjectId();
const c = ObjectId();
const d = ObjectId();

db.getCollection('test').insertMany([
{
    arr: [a, b]
},
{
    arr: [a, b, c]
},
{
    arr: [d]
},
{
    arr: [a, d]
}
])
```

Now I perform this aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        dups: {$push: '$arr'}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        noDupsDoesNotWork: {
            $setUnion: '$dups'
        }
}
}
])
```

And receive:

```
{
    "noDupsDoesNotWork" : [ 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0d"), 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0e")
        ], 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0d"), 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0e"), 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0f")
        ], 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0d"), 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c10")
        ], 
        [ 
            ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c10")
        ]
    ]
}
```

Which is what I don't understand since [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) is said to work on an array of arrays. In my example I'm expecting it to perform set union on 4 arrays.
However, if I perform this aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        dups: {$push: '$arr'}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        flattened: {
            $reduce: {
                input: '$dups',
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this']}
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        noDups: {$setUnion: '$flattened'}
    }
}
])
```

Then I will get the expected result:

```
{
    "noDups" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0d"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0e"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0f"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c10")
    ]
}
```

But this time `$setUnion` works on a single array of objects, and not an array of arrays.

I am all the more baffled since if I explicitly pass the four sub-arrays I will get the expected result:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        dups: {$push: '$arr'}
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        explicit: {
            $setUnion: [
                {$arrayElemAt: ['$dups', 0]},
                {$arrayElemAt: ['$dups', 1]},
                {$arrayElemAt: ['$dups', 2]},
                {$arrayElemAt: ['$dups', 3]},
            ]
        }
    }
}
])
```

What am I missing here?

For clarity, this is the desired output (detailed above but added again):

```
{
    "noDups" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0d"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0e"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c0f"), 
        ObjectId("5b839b38f6db291c78201c10")
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The before last code snippet, which is an array of 4 distinct ObjectIds.

Comment: `$setUnion` takes array of expressions with each expression resolving to array. From the docs: _The arguments can be any valid expression as long as they each resolve to an array_. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion)

Answer (score 1):

Why is this happening?
Well this is actually a "feature" of Mongo believe it or not.
There is an open [feature change request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31991) you can track. but let's understand [why](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31786?focusedCommentId=1724156&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1724156):

> There are a class of expressions which accept multiple arguments, expressed as an array. (In the code, these inherit from ExpressionNary.) For any such n-ary expression, which I will call $nary, the syntax {$nary: "$myArg"} is simply a shorthand for {$nary: ["$myArg"]}. These two expression are identical in meaning.

So this unique class of expressions include many operators, one of them is [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/). Mongo's expression languages just parses any '$arg' as ['$arg'] for these operators.
This is why the 'unexpected' behaviour happens when you used the `$dups` expression but does not happen when you explicitly write the same values.

I will just re-iterate the (best) word around this for people who didn't read your full question, you want to use [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) after you flatten the array using [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) like so:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        flat: {
            $setUnion: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: '$myArray',
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {$concatArrays: ['$$this', '$$value']}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```